# Where can I ask about feedback on Cloud Architecture setup?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Currently I am thinking a lot about a new architecture for deploying our 2 applications in the cloud (moving from CloudFoundry PaaS to Docker).

I know how we're doing it currently and I have a imho well-defined setup/architecture in my mind.

It's **not** about choosing a technology, asking for opinions (at least not how I see it) but it's not a pure programming activity of course.

Is it allowed to share a 'logical architecture' with all technologies chosen and ask for feedback whether this is the right approach to go?

Or basically as asking for a *right approach* is off-topic for sure - is it OK to ask whether the architecture misses any items or contains any obvious issues? And if so, where on StackExchange would I do this?

Comment: According to your description of it you'll be welcome on https://devops.stackexchange.com